# Как написать tearDown() при использовании py.test?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, pytest

Если кратко, то суть вопроса : где в py.test возможность написать tearDown() ?

Очень привык при организации модульного тестирования использовать тест.фреймворки xUnit-семейства. При разработке на python для этого применяю unittest библиотеку из стандартного набора библиотека.

В xUnit-фрейворках для сборки мусора после себя пишется tearDown() метод, который программист пишет код приводящий тест.систему в состояние, которое было до теста или близкое к этому.

Сейчас же решил перейти на py.test из-за лаконичности тестов. Но увидел, что привычного tearDown() нету. При просмотре того что советует гугл увидел yield_fixture.

Это единственный способ или нет? Если не единственный, то какой предпочтительнее и почему?

**UPD**:
Моя цель, вообще убрать из кода использование unittest, чтобы ни одной зависимости не было!

Comment: "When building test fixtures using TestCase, the setUp() and tearDown() methods can be overridden to provide initialization and cleanup for the fixture." - https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: Поправил свой вопрос UPD-комментарием

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует два способа написания tearDown():

1. Использовать pytest.yield_fixture. Об этом в стандартной документации к py.test: [Fixture functions using “yield” / context manager integration](http://pytest.org/latest/yieldfixture.html)
2. Использовать Fixture.Request, вернее его методом addfinalizer(). ОБ этом в примере на сайте pytest.org: [Making test result information available in fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html?highlight=addfinalizer#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures)

В обоих случаях достаточно импортировать модуль pytest и тогда оба способа будут доступны. Примеры как это примерно может выглядеть:

Способ №1:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture
def application():
    _app = create_app(configName='testing')
    _app_ctx = _app.app_context()
    _app_ctx.push()
    db.create_all()
    yield _app
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
    _app_ctx.pop()
```

Способ №2:

```
@pytest.fixture
def application():
    _app = create_app(configName='testing')
    _app_ctx = _app.app_context()
    _app_ctx.push()
    db.create_all()
    def _finalize()
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        _app_ctx.pop()
    request.addfinalizer(_finalize)
    return _app
```

Answer (score 0):

начиная с версии pytest 3.0 обычные фикстуры могут содержать yield